# What's the different between CharacterView and UnicodeScalarView of the String type

Tags: swift, string, unicode

The following two code practically did the same thing

```
for character in "Dog!".characters {
    print(character)
}

for character in "Dog!".unicodeScalars {
    print(character)
}
```

However, when I check for more detail information behind the sense, I found the difference. The `characters` property is the type of `CharacterView` while `unicodeScalars` is the type of `UnicodeScalarView`.

**Question**:

What's the difference between them?

Which property is preferred for what situation? (would be nice to have an example)

Many Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30 is a good overview. – Try it with `""` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to the difference between a `Character` and `UnicodeScalar`.

> ## Unicode Scalars
>
> Behind the scenes, Swift’s native String type is built from Unicode scalar values. A Unicode scalar is a unique 21-bit number for a character or modifier, such as U+0061 for LATIN SMALL LETTER A ("a"), or U+1F425 for FRONT-FACING BABY CHICK ("").
>
> ...
>
> ## Extended Grapheme Clusters
>
> Every instance of Swift’s Character type represents a single extended grapheme cluster. An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of one or more Unicode scalars that (when combined) produce a single human-readable character.
>
> Here’s an example. The letter é can be represented as the single Unicode scalar é (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE, or U+00E9). However, the same letter can also be represented as a pair of scalars—a standard letter e (LATIN SMALL LETTER E, or U+0065), followed by the COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT scalar (U+0301). The COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT scalar is graphically applied to the scalar that precedes it, turning an e into an é when it is rendered by a Unicode-aware text-rendering system.

From the [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293) section of the [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309).

In most cases that I can think of you'll want to be dealing with `Character` instances, as they as the smallest unit of Human language. I can't imagine a situation where you'd want to operate on a modifier without considering the full extended grapheme cluster.